# Regular Expression to get substring from main string

Tags: regex

I am trying to get sub-string based on some pattern. trying to fetch first number which should not be in first character of main string.

**Strings:**

```
BRUSPAZ 8MG
BRUSPAZ MG
BRUSPAZ 10 MG
BRUSPAZ10 MG
AVAS 40
AVAS 40 TEST 2TABS
MICROCEF CV 200 TABS 
1CROCIN DS 240 MG / 5 ML SUSPENSION
```

**My Regular Expression :** `/(\d+)( )?(MG)?/`

[image]

**Required Output:**

[image]

Comment: How is the `10` in `BRUSPAZ10` not in the first word?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry not in first word, it should not be first character

Comment: can you show us the expected outputs instead of an image, i can't check the image (company rules :()

Comment: Do you want a pure regex solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex:

```
(?<!^)(\d+)(\s*MG)?
```

- I changed the `( )?` to `\s*` so as to account for other kinds of whitespace and more than one of them.
- I added a `(?<!^)`. This is a negative lookbehind, looking for `^` - the start of the string. Basically it says that "there should not be the start of the string before the digits".
- If you run this regex line by line, and turning of the global modifier, you will not match the 5 in the last line.

If you want to match decimals as well, use this:

```
(?<!^)(\d+\.\d+)(\s*MG)?
```

Comment: Try using a negative look ahead in your regular expression. Try looking that up. If you still can't figure out, ask a new question. @JunedAnsari

Comment: it does not extract float number eg. ALVACE 2.5MG

Comment: @JunedAnsari You should have said that in the question! Anyway, see the edit.